Whether $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$?
In Huybrechts's Complex Geometry An Introduction, the author say
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)
$$
Because $i$ times a number is equivalent to rotating the number by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ conterclockwise. So, I feel $i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ is $-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. Therefore, $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.  Is that the right idea?

If a function is complex differentiable, you should be able to evaluate the limit definition of the derivative along any path in $\mathbb{C}$ and obtain the same result. Taking a path parallel to the $x$-axis yields $\frac{d}{dz} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, while taking a path parallel to the $y$-axis yields $\frac{d}{dz} = -i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$. Adding these and dividing by two gives the formula you stated.

Another way of thinking about it, is as a change of coordinates. Instead of using the independent coordinates $x$ and $y$ we want to use $z$ and $\overline{z}$ (complex conjugate). The formula can then be derived from $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ using $x = \frac{z + \overline{z}}{2}$ and $y = \frac{z - \overline{z}}{2i}$ together with $\frac{\partial z}{\partial z} = 1$ and $\frac{\partial \overline{z}}{\partial z} = 0$ (since we treat them as independent coordinates).

Yes, this is correct if you interpret the $i$-multiplication as a rotation of the derivative.
